# GMSMapView's animateTo() moves camera to incorrect position when using autolayout

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have a `GMSMapView` that doesn't fill the entire screen, but about 2/3 of it in an `iPad application`. When the `UIViewController` is invoked, the map waits for a user location update and animates the `MapView` to center on that position:

```swift
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let location = locations.last!
        if(!has_first_location) {
            has_first_location = true
            let pos = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withTarget: location.coordinate, 
                                               zoom: 18.0)
            self.mapView!.animate(to: pos)
        }
    }
```

The preface here is that this problem exists in iOS 12.1, but not iOS 12.0.1 (both real devices, 9.7 inch iPads). Here is an image of the view:

[image: View screenshot]

As you can see, the view doesn't center over the user, but southeast of them. This also happens if I draw a `GMSPolyline` or similar, and try to center with padding around it's bounds. This behavior does *not* occur when I move to the camera position instantly instead of animating to it (i.e. with `moveTo()` instead of `animateTo()`.

There are constraints tacking the top, right, and bottom edges of the map to the superview, and one keeping it stuck to the right edge of the sidebar. The `GMSMapView` isn't created programatically, it's set in the storyboard.

Currently I've tried setting frames on the sublayers, and this seems to be the root of the problem. I just do not know how to reliably pick which sublayer I need to re-frame, and it also seems like a less-than-ideal solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you debug view hierarchy?

Comment: @RajeshKumarR I just tried this, looks like all the layers of the MapView are of expected size: https://i.imgur.com/tRyioge.png

Comment: this might happen if use equal to other view's(h,w) constraint, try to remove that constraint

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the exact same issue when displaying the GMSMapView in a modal with the default modalPresentationStyle. Once I switched to `modalPresentationStyle = .fullscreen`
The GMSMapView centered perfectly on the locations passed to `animateTo()`.